# to read and write contents to a tar.gz file in linux

Tags: c, linux, gzip, tar

I am trying to open a tar.gz file and read the contents of that file into a buffer. I want to create another tar.gz file and write the buffer to the newly created tar.gz file. Would the new file be same as the previous one? The code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    int len,len1;
    int length=0;
    char *buf=malloc(1024);

    char *buf1=malloc(1024);
    fp=fopen("/home/sharwari/Downloads/criu-1.4/3049.tar.gz","rb");

    while((len=fread(buf,1024,1,fp))>0)
    {
        printf("%s",buf);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    fp1=fopen("/home/sharwari/imp5.tgz","wb");

    if(fp1==NULL)
        printf("\n\terror in creating file...");

    len1=fwrite(buf,1,strlen(buf),fp1);


    printf("\n\t No. of bytes written: %d",len1);

    fclose(fp1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to intermix your reads and your writes in a single reading loop.  PS - `printf("%s", buf);` when buf is binary data will likely print a lot of garbage and stop at the first zero byte encountered.  Similarly, don't use strlen on binary data as it too will stop at the first zero byte encountered.  Instead, use the return value from fread to pass the write size to fwrite.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but there are a number of issues with your code. Including at least:

1. The while loop will result in discarding all except the last 1024 bytes. Because you keep reading 1024 bytes and overwriting the contents of buf.
2. You cannot use strlen on binary data.
3. You need more error checking on fread to determine whether you successfully read all the way to the end of the file or whether an error occured. Read the fread man page (it will point you to feof and ferror).
4. It's good practice to free any malloced memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are calling `fwrite(buf,1,strlen(buf),fp1);` with wrong arguments.
   It should have been

`fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`

2. You are trying to read in a block of `1024`bytes which will fail if the file size is less than `1024` bytes

With the below code, you are trying to copy byte by byte from source file to 
the destination file.
You can refer the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    int len,len1 = 0;
    char buf[1];

    fp = fopen("/home/sharwari/Downloads/criu-1.4/3049.tar.gz","rb");
    fp1 = fopen("/home/sharwari/imp5.tgz","wb");

    if (fp == NULL || fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("\n\terror in creating file...");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((len = fread(&buf, 1, 1, fp)) > 0) {
       len1 += fwrite(&buf, 1, 1, fp1);
    }

    printf("\n\t No. of bytes written: %d",len1);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it not a bit of overkill fread-ing into a buffer. By definition fopen, fread etc are already buffered and deal with actual io in an optimal manner. The code should be more like

while(1) {

if(i=fgetc(in)==EOF) break;

else fputc(i,out);

}